# Отфильтровать теги beautifulsoup по содержанию атрибута

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Имеется условный html документ с различными тегами.
Мне нужно получить текст из заголовков, текст из абзацев и картинки. Но картинки только определенного типа, у которых атрибут src содержит текст "800.jpeg"
То есть из картинок:

```
<img src="egtywgyugrwuygryurgyugwuygwyugruygrw__600.svg">
<img src="egtywgyugrwuygryurgyugwuygwyugruygrw__800.jpeg">
```

мне нужна только вторая.

Использую следующий код:

```
for item in BeautifulSoup(sample_html, 'lxml').find_all(["p", "h2", "h3", "img"]):
            if item.name == 'h2':
                print(item.getText(strip=True))
            if item.name == 'h3':
                print(item.getText(strip=True))
            if item.name == 'p':
                print(item.getText(strip=True))
            if item.name == 'source':
```

Вопрос как сформулировать правило для картинки. Пробовал разные варианты с регулярками, но ничего не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись без регулярок

Вначале получаем содержимое `src` потом с помощью среза получаем последние восемь элементов

```
def f(list_):
    return [el for el in list_ if el.get("src")[-8:] == "800.jpeg"]
    
page = """
<img src="egtywgyugrwuygryurgyugwuygwyugruygrw__600.svg">
<img src="egtywgyugrwuygryurgyugwuygwyugruygrw__800.jpeg"> 
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

print(f(soup.find_all("img")))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [<img src="egtywgyugrwuygryurgyugwuygwyugruygrw__800.jpeg">]
> ```

Comment: Спасибо! Решение не выглядит оптимальным, но в моем случае работает